# How to set user passwords in ejabberd?

Tags: ios, xmpp, ejabberd

I installed eJabberd to test my iOS application's XMPP functionality. I can log in with the admin user name and password. But I have created two users at the "Access Control List". When I try to log in with those users, i get an error saying the password is incorrect. I'm currently testing with Message application in Mac OS.

Do they have a default password? if not, how to set the password for the users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running eJabberD on osx or linux you can use ejabberdctl to create users and set passwords. http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man8/ejabberdctl.8.html

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the web admin panel of Ejabberd server to add users. To use the admin panel use the following :

"http://localhost:5280/admin"

It will ask the user name and password for the admin and is the one you configured during the ejabberd installation.

Comment: This password part of this Ejabbered is very confusing. After installing and adding the line, where do we make the admin password???? really

Comment: Ejabberd ask for the admin credentials at the time of installation. Once you set the admin credentials and install the Ejabberd, you can use admin panel to further add the users and manage the server. By default the admin username/password added in the Mnesia (default) database. Please let me know if you need any assistance on this.

Comment: how do you set new user passwords from the admin panel?

Comment: you can create a user from admin panel and set username and password. You can also map database with mysql or sql server (for example) and than add user info in user table.